# LyX: "No file found" error when inserting an image on a figure float

Tags: graphics, floats, lyx

I am facing a strange error with one figure in LyX.

Inside a figure float I have inserted a figure using LyX's GUI. I have browsed to the file's location and selected the png file.  I am seeing an error saying "No file found!" instead of displaying the miniature of the image. All other images are okay.

Any idea of what the issue might be? Or is this just a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the error from LyX or when you compile LaTeX? What is your operating system?

Comment: I see the error diplayed in the preview of the image within my LyX's document. Windows 7, 64bit.

Comment: I don't think I've seen this error. Not sure what's going on. When you select the file, is it saved as an absolute path or a relative path? Perhaps change it (manually edit the path) to the other, just to try something different.